# teamcity dynamically add or change parameter in build step

Tags: asp.net, svn, nunit, teamcity

i am trying to using teamcity to watch then auto build/test a set of branches within a main folder,so i set up a build configuration in teamcity to watch a main folder which include many branches of the same project,once there are new commit in one of those branches, teamcity will call a .bat file in first build step to generate some parameters then return that branch URl which has new commit, then compile/run unit test only in that branch.

my trouble is i don't know how to pass this URl return by that .bat file to the next build step, what i consider is to set this URL into a configuration parameter using following statement in command line runner.

```
%##teamcity[setParameter name='subpath' value='getsubpath.bat %otherparameter%']%
```

unfortunately this code do not occur any error and do not set a new parameter name 'subpath'.

is that i am using this 'setParameter' statement incorrect? or it is not available in command line runner. any one can give a example of using ##teamcity[setParameter.....] or some idea about this scenario？

Answer (score 1):

From your question I assume you are using a vcs trigger to fire a build on new commits.
In this case you can use the already defined %teamcity.build.branch% variable which will give you the branch which the build got trigger on.
Configure your Branch specification in the vcs settings, and the branch filter in the vcs trigger to select the branches you want to working with in the build configuration.
For this see http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Working+with+Feature+Branches

If you don't want to use this solution, you should echo/print the line you wrote inside your bat which produces the URI:
echo "##teamcity[setParameter name='subpath' value='%variableContainsTheURI%']"

Where 'subpath' is a TeamCity variable. I'm not sure if you can use configuration parameter. If it's not working, just use TeamCity environment variable.

Comment: config parameter should work, key is to echo the line with setParameter